Looking for a brake cable cap larger than standard size
Does anybody know what kind of brake cable end cap I need for this larger than standard size socket? I used a brake cable adjuster as a temporary solution.


I'd suggest you stop doing that immediately - you're at risk of widening the gap even further.

See also https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/50618/ferrule-size-for-a-road-brake-cable-housing-slot

If i'm not mistaken, the left most groove is not for an end stop, but for a hydraulic brake line. If i am correct, you will find the same size at the other end of the gab (i.e near the saddle tube on the top tube). Also, you will either have disk brake mounts, or your frame was designed for use with hydraulic rim brakes.
You should be able to route a complete outer brake cable through that groove.
That means, you will have a complete outer all the way from the brake lever to the brake itself.

I never thought this old frame would be hydraulic disc brake compatible. It is more than 15 years old. Was there hydraulic disc brakes available then?

@Ender you make me feel reeeeally old ... ! :-) i know Magura made their first hydraulic disk brake in 1996. Not sure about other manufacturers though.

I'm 44 year old :) This is a Geotech branded MTB. It has been a lot of time since I bought this frame. After your suggestion I checked and saw that both the frame and fork has the mounting holes for disc brake calipers. I hadn't aware of their existence before. So that socket is for disc brake cable which is wider than rim brake cables?

@Ender it's for hydraulic brake lines. those of course need to run all the way from the lever to the caliper, contrary to brake cables. There are mechanical disk brakes that work with cables, and those are the same cables as for mechanical rim brakes.

Alright. I will continue with rim brakes. Even if I make it full cable it doesn't stay on the socket because it's too thin.

I have seen some older bikes with an inset that goes into a larger diameter braze on cable stop. The larger size is designed to allow hydraulic brake hose to pass thru it. The insert is available from Jagwire part number CHA056. They are available at a number of online retailers or you could try your local shop. It is a small part so shipping may be more than the part itself.

That part is 5mm in diameter. It's the same size as common brake cable end caps. Maybe this socket was designed for barrel adjusters?

@Ender that part is actually a cable stop and inserts into the mount point, just as mikes suggested. Personally, i don't like them much (they tend to get lost) and prefer routing a complete outer in such cases. But they do work as intended.

I might be overreacting/misjudging, but the socket/stop doesn't look right in the photo. I'd be concerned about the ferrule popping/sliding out altogether.
And if I ever had a concern like that then I would probably run the wire in a single, full-length housing from the brake lever all the way to the noodle (or the last stop or wherever the housing would normally stop).

It was like that before I cut it off. It was popping out so I wanted to fix it with a ferrule but I messed it up.

Full length housing is an option, but it won't fit through those stop blocks, which are shaped like a cup but with a slot in the side.  It would be hard to get a drill  in-line to widen them too.

I am slightly concerned that the right-most wire passes on the left side of the head tube - that doesn't look right either.

@Criggie if you cannot just snap the housing in, pushing it through with the ferrule removed should be possible

Start by popping all three lines out of their holders.
One is for the rear brake and is the one with the thicker cable. The other two will be the front and rear derailleur, and will use a thinner cable.
It is possible that one of the three positions is sized for the larger brake cable ferrule, and they may be in the wrong slots.
Brake ferrules are normally 5.0mm in diameter, but 5.5mm is also a common size.
Gear cable ferrules are 4.0 or 4.5mm but there are always variations.
In my experience, generally the metal ferrules you crimp on tend to be smaller OD, whereas any plasticish ones are often larger.

Now if your mounting point is already wider than the largest ferrules you can find, it may work to make or find a bushing that can fill the slot and either hold your existing brake ferrule, OR just make a custom ferrule that has a hole for the inner cable to pass through, a standard socket for the cable outer, but has a larger OD to fit whatever the frame's slot is sized to now.
If the slot is oversized, you might be tempted to hammer it back into place. I suspect this has a 10% chance of working, and a 60% chance of cracking the weld/braze, and 10% chance of detaching the fitting completely. That would be bad.
